# Check for a specific suffix by RegEx and select entire match including suffix

Tags: javascript, regex

First of all, this is my first question in the community hence please pardon my wrongs Experts! I am learning regex and faced a scenario where I am failing to create answer by myself.

Let's say if there is humongous paragraph, can we first match on the basis of a specific suffix (say '%') and Only then go back and select the desired logic including suffix?

e.g. part of the text is "abcd efghMNP 0.40 % ijkl mnopSNP -3.20 % xyz". 
Now in this, if you notice - and I got this much - that there is pattern like

```
/([MS]NP[\s\d\.-%]+)/
```

I want to replace "MNP 0.40 %" or "SNP -3.20 %" with blank. replacing part seems easy :) But the problem is with all my learning I am not able to select desired ONLY IF there exists a '%' at the end of match.

The sequence of match I wish to reach at is -- if suffix '%' exists, then match the previous pattern, and if successful then select everything including suffix and replace with empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several expressions that would do so, for instance this one with added constraints:

```
[A-Z]{3}\s+[-+]?[0-9.]+\s*%
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /[A-Z]{3}\s+[-+]?[0-9.]+\s*%/gm;
const str = `abcd efghMNP 0.40 % ijkl mnopSNP -3.20 % xyz

"MNP 0.40 %" or "SNP -3.20 %"`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/2aS7s0/1/)

Or a simplified version would be:

```
[A-Z]{3}(.*?)%
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/jsoApU/1/)

Comment: Thanks, and agreed too, Emma. ([MS]NP[\s\.\d-]+%) would also do. But are these checking conditionally like IF '%' exists THEN?

Comment: @Avinash as you are using JavaScript i would suggest, let the JS do `If else` part and regex helping you in matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can not go back in the matching if you have encountered a suffix `%`, but what you can do is to make it part of the pattern so that is has to be matched.

In Javascript you could perform a zero length [lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=` making sure that what is on the right contains a pattern or in this case a `%` but that will not be a real benefit in this case as you want it to be part of the match.

A bit more specific match could be:

```
[MS]NP\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*%
```

- `[MS]NP` Match `M` or `S` followed by NP
- `\s*-?` Match 0+ times a whitespace char followed by an optional `-`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits followed by an optional part to match a dot and 1+ digits
- `\s*%` Match 0+ whitespace chars followed by matching `%`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8zDu17/1)

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks Bird :) The "cannot" in 'You can not go back in the matching if you have encountered a suffix %' was what I was trying to break but it seems it's really something solid worth bowing before. Thanks a ton for confirming it :)

Comment: I believe that in .NET regex you have a RightToLeft option. See this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989606/match-regex-from-right-to-left

Comment: And perhaps this question can be helpful. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203378/regex-match-back-to-a-period-or-start-of-string

Comment: Brilliant Idea .. THANKS A LOT for providing the second link. I'm grateful. This idea will work to my motto as it can base on the given '%' sign and then goes backwards as he shows for the word 'regex' in the example. Just great! :) May God Bless You